# Working with divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum, divisor-counting-function

Compute ∅ (40), (124), (124) and check the equality in Σ∅() = 40.

Here's what I've done so far:

Not really sure about the summation equality.

`∅ (40)` = ∅ (5) x ∅ (8) => 4x4 = 16

`(124)` = 1+2+4+1+62+124 = 224

`(124)` = 1,2,4,31,62,124 = 6

`Σ∅()` = 40 => [Not sure how to compute this]

Comment: Your question is pretty hard to read.  Your "work" is all bunched up together, and it's hard to tell what's what.  Consider breaking up what you've done into paragraphs, and explain clearly what you're confused about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summation equality says that for any natural number $n$, $$n = \varphi d + \varphi d' + \varphi d'' + \cdots$$ where $d, d', d''$ etc. are all the positive divisors of $n$.  Since the divisors of $40$ are $1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 20, 40$, you need to check that $$40 = \varphi 1 + \varphi 2 + \varphi 4 + \varphi 5 + \varphi 8 + \varphi 10 + \varphi 20 + \varphi 40$$